# При простом клике на кнопку всплывает окно, а при клике на кнопку формы - нет

Tags: html, ajax, html-form, всплывающее-окно

Есть форма заказа, результат которой обрабатывается без перезагрузки страницы в результате действий которой должно появиться всплывающее окно, сигнализирующее об успешном выполнении. Вопрос: почему при нажатии на простую кнопку оформление всплывающее окно открывается, а при нажатии на кнопку `submit` нет? вот [фидл](http://jsfiddle.net/vGAsL/69/)

```js
$(".confirmation").click(function(){
 $(this).magnificPopup({
  items: {
  src: '#confirmation',
  type: 'inline'
  }
  });
});

$('#form_id').submit(function(){
$.ajax({
type : 'POST',
url : '/my-account',
data : $("#form_id").serializeArray(),
success: function () { 
$(".confirmation").magnificPopup({
items: {
src: '#confirmation',
type: 'inline'
}
});
alert('sucsess');// проверяем работу скрипта в случае успеха 
},
error :function(){
alert('fail');// проверяем работу скрипта в случае неудачи 
}
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/dimsemenov/Magnific-Popup/master/dist/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>
<script src="http://a.vimeocdn.com/js/froogaloop2.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgithub.com/dimsemenov/Magnific-Popup/master/dist/magnific-popup.css">
https://rawgithub.com/dimsemenov/Magnific-Popup/master/dist/magnific-popup.css

<form id="form_id" action="/my-account" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="certform">
 <input type="text" value="Имя"/>
 <input type="password" value="Пароль"/>
 <div>Сертификат: <input type="file" name="cert1"/></div>
<div><input class="confirmation" type="submit" value="Добавить"/></div>
            </form>
<div id="confirmation" class="mfp-hide">
<h2>Результат</h2>
<p>Имя</p>
<p>Пароль</p>
<p>Сертификат №</p>
</div>
<br /><br />
<button class="confirmation">оформление</button>
```

Comment: "при нажатии на простую форму отправить ..." как это понимать?

Comment: @lexxl описался - "на простую кнопку оформление"

Comment: при нажатии на `<button>Оформление</button>` форма срабатывает, а при `<input type="submit" value="Добавить"/>` не срабатывает?

Comment: @lexxl нет, окно всплывающее, а не форма при нажатии на кнопку - гляньте фидл вверху - вопросы сразу отпадут

Answer (score 1):

По нажатию "submit" происходит перезагрузка страницы, и обработчик `success` не успевает выстрелить. Добавьте `return false;` в обработчик `submit`, чтобы этого избежать.

```
$('#form_id').submit(function(){
  ...
  return false;
});
```

Comment: хмм.. получается забавная штука - всплывающее окно появляется после 2го клика http://jsfiddle.net/vGAsL/70/

Comment: @Вася У Вас показ всплывающего окна навешен на клик кнопки и на ajax.ssuccess в сабмите формы. Обратите внимание на сообщение "fail" в консоли фидла.

Comment: эмм, не совсем понятно, что вы предлагаете - убрать 1 навес?

Comment: @Вася  используйте в фидле `<button class="confirmation1">оформление</button>` и `$(".confirmation1").click(function(){...`, чтобы не было "забавных штук"

Comment: так? одни фейлы показывает http://jsfiddle.net/vGAsL/71/

Comment: естественно - http://fiddle.jshell.net/my-account  не существует

Comment: на реальном сервере с `return false;` и ` $(this).magnificPopup({})` модальное окно появляется при втором клике `ajax` не срабатывает, форма не отправляется. без `return false;` `ajax` срабатывает, но модалка не появляется - как-то так..

Comment: @Вася Вы неправильно пользуетесь плагином magnificPopup. Прочитайте, пожалуйста, документацию и примеры http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/

Comment: но все же не вижу в документации реализацию под мой пример, как обрабатывать правильно `ajax` запрос все равно никак не могу разобрать

Comment: и все же - есть решение моей проблемы или вы сами не знаете?